# Techniques to composite geometry and volumetrics together for an animation

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, volumetrics

Hello everyone I hope you are hanging in there!

I spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out with Stack and YouTube but still can't wrap my head around this.

The scene below will eventually become a small tabletop environment with birds, wind, flowing river, etc. The hardest element for me to add though is the CLOUDS because volumetrics are so tricky. My thought, since I am working with an online render farm (RenderStreet) , was to separate the clouds on one layer and send it in for rendering then set the clouds as a holdout and send in the other half. In theory I would end up with 2 videos that I could stitch together and this way the clouds would be isolated and easier to render whereas rendering everything together would take 90 minutes for 1 frame.
[image]
I have seen a lot of compositing material out there but not much specific to animation. Am I on the right track or is there a way better method to get this done?

Thank you all so much!

Comment: You are on the right track. Compositing an animation is exactly like compositing a picture (an animation is just a sequence of pictures), so any tutorial will work for both.

Comment: It all depends on the kind of volumetrics you want to add. Clouds would need to project shadows into the landscape, and scatter light, so the quality of the shadows would neet to be affected. The tricky part is how to recreate the interaction of volumetrics and how those are broken by the geometry of the landscape. If you are going to use a render farm anyway, try to create all of it on a single pass.